# LIKE compare a list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of names like so:

"John"
"Alan"

and a list of People that have all sorts of names

I can search through my people table for any names that match my list like this:

```
people = people.Where(x => names.Contains(x.Name));
```

However, this performs an exact match.  How do I modify my query to be able to do a LIKE search on items in the names list?

Ie, I would like my original names list to find people in the people table that have names like

"John Smith"
"Bob Alanson"

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any` and `Contains` in which you already know how to use it.

```
var names = new List<string>() { "John", "Alan" };
var people = new List<string>() { "John Smith", "Bob Alanson" };
var result = people.Where(x => names.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

The result is

```
John Smith
Bob Alanson
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `Any` and `string.Contains`

```
people = people.Where(x => names.Any(n => x.Name.Contains(n)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
people = people.Where(x => names.Like(x.Name, "%key%"));
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a `Like` method for `List`

Answer (score 0):

Using **Contains** is close to **Like (%pattern%)**. And some "Tom Johnson" will be selected to result collection. I prefer to use **StartsWith** (which implements **Like(pattern%)**) for filtering by name.